# parsing of xml response using c#

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I want to get the list of all the `<url>` present in this `xml response.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sessionState xmlns="http://citrix.com/delivery-services/1-0/sessionstate" enumeration="full">
   <sessions>
      <session id="zyxw9876">
         <serverType>win32</serverType>
         <launchIca>
            <url>http://www.example.com/Store/session/v1/zyxw9876/launch/ica</url>
         </launchIca>
         <initialapp>MSPaint</initialapp>
         <initialappresourceaggregated>false</initialappresourceaggregated>
         <initialappresourceid>XA1.MSPaint</initialappresourceid>
         <publishername>Farm1</publishername>
      </session>
      <session id="3e4d5f6g">
         <serverType>win32</serverType>
         <launchIca>
            <url>http://www.example.com/Store/session/v1/3e4d5f6g/launch/ica</url>
         </launchIca>
         <initialapp>Notepad</initialapp>
         <initialappresourceaggregated>false</initialappresourceaggregated>
         <initialappresourceid>XA1.Notepad</initialappresourceid>
         <publishername>Farm1</publishername>
      </session>
   </sessions>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: What is stopping you? what had you tried already?

Comment: Then go ahead, parse the XML, extract the URL-nodes... rather simple! What is your actual question? I'd kindly advice you to read the [how-to-ask-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as in its current state your 'question' can not and will not be answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview). With it you can do this:

```
string rawXml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<sessionState xmlns=""http://citrix.com/delivery-services/1-0/sessionstate"" enumeration=""full"">
<sessions>
    <session id=""zyxw9876"">
        <serverType>win32</serverType>
        <launchIca>
            <url>http://www.example.com/Store/session/v1/zyxw9876/launch/ica</url>
        </launchIca>
        <initialapp>MSPaint</initialapp>
        <initialappresourceaggregated>false</initialappresourceaggregated>
        <initialappresourceid>XA1.MSPaint</initialappresourceid>
        <publishername>Farm1</publishername>
    </session>
    <session id=""3e4d5f6g"">
        <serverType>win32</serverType>
        <launchIca>
            <url>http://www.example.com/Store/session/v1/3e4d5f6g/launch/ica</url>
        </launchIca>
        <initialapp>Notepad</initialapp>
        <initialappresourceaggregated>false</initialappresourceaggregated>
        <initialappresourceid>XA1.Notepad</initialappresourceid>
        <publishername>Farm1</publishername>
    </session>
</sessions>
</sessionState>";

XElement xml = XElement.Load(new StringReader(rawXml));
List<string> urls = xml.Descendants().Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("url"))
    .Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(urls.Count);
foreach (string str in urls)
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```